# Spring security with OAuth2 and Github to only allow developers in an organization to use certain APIs

Tags: spring-boot, github, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a set of apis that I only want developers in an organization in github to use. To authenticate the user, I've used OAuth of github. But using Spring security with oauth does not seem to do it as it allows developers who are not in the organization to use it. How do I go about this?

Comment: Can you add more detail like the code which you tried etc ?

Comment: @YogeshPrajapati
Adding `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` to the pom enables oauth on all apis. 
Then created a oauth app on github. Now, when I try out any api, the request is intercepted and redirected to oauth of github where I allow access of my github.
After this, the link is forwared to the protected api. Here, I want the api to accessed only when the user is added to the organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this [spring.io](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) tutorial has an example for this exact use case:

```java
@Bean
public OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService(WebClient rest) {
    DefaultOAuth2UserService delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
    return request -> {
        OAuth2User user = delegate.loadUser(request);
        if (!"github".equals(request.getClientRegistration().getRegistrationId())) {
            return user;
        }

        OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = new OAuth2AuthorizedClient
                (request.getClientRegistration(), user.getName(), request.getAccessToken());
        String url = user.getAttribute("organizations_url");
        List<Map<String, Object>> orgs = rest
                .get().uri(url)
                .attributes(oauth2AuthorizedClient(client))
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(List.class)
                .block();

        if (orgs.stream().anyMatch(org -> "spring-projects".equals(org.get("login")))) {
            return user;
        }

        throw new OAuth2AuthenticationException(new OAuth2Error("invalid_token", "Not in Spring Team", ""));
    };
}
```

Comment: I ended up using filterchain to do this